# Async Postback Control And Update Progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have Async File Upload

```
 <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload2"  EnableViewState="true" Width="400"  UploaderStyle="Modern" OnClientUploadComplete="showDiv" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" ClientIDMode="AutoID" runat="server" />
```

i have update progress in master page which works fine in all situations
except when there is async postback using above file upload control.
How can i show update progress when AsyncFileUpload_UploadComplete is getting fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?
http://aspalliance.com/1442_Building_AJAX_Enabled_File_Uploading_System_with_Progress_Bar_Using_ASPNET_20.4